# Req.flash(errors) Not Displaying -NodeJS 5.7.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to make it so when a user enters an email that is already in the db to let the user know that that account email is already registered.
I am getting the correct error from mongo db but I dont want to display all that junk. I want it to just display my error on my signup page in the form saying something like "This email address is registered already".

MongoDB Response:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: jcommerce.users.$email_1 dup key: { : "james12345@gmail.com" }
   at Function.MongoError.create (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
   at toError (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:114:22)
   at C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:616:23
   at handleCallback (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
   at C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\unordered.js:470:9
   at handleCallback (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
   at resultHandler (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\unordered.js:417:5)
   at commandCallback (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:936:9)
   at Callbacks.emit (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:116:3)
   at null.messageHandler (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:282:23)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\jcommerce\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:273:22)
   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
   at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
   at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

Route Class

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var User = require('../models/user')

router.get('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('accounts/signup', {
        errors: req.flash('errors')
    });
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
        var user = new User();

        user.profile.name = req.body.name;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.password = req.body.password;

        // Validate
        User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function (err, existingUser) {
            if (existingUser) {
                req.flash('errors', 'Account with that email address already exists');
                return res.redirect('/signup');
            }
            else {
                // save user to database
                user.save(function(err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }

                    return res.redirect('/');


                });
            }
        }); // Mongoose method find one document in db
});

module.exports = router;
```

EJS

```
    <% layout('layout') -%>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <% if (errors.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"> 
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <%= errors %>
            </div>
     <%  } %>

        <form method="post">
            <h1> Signup! </h1>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label="name"> Name: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label="name"> Email: </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label="name"> Password: </label>
                <input type="passwod" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Server.js AKA app.js**
// Require library we want to use

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var engine = require('ejs-mate');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // parses cookies and put it on the request object in the middleware
var flash = require('express-flash');

var User = require('./models/user');

// App is reffering to express objects, bc we want to use express objects
var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodbconnectionstring', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Connected to the database");
    }
});

//Middleware - logs requests in cmd
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Express can parse data format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "James@@@@#"
}));
app.use(flash());
app.engine('ejs', engine)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// body parser takes the body of request and parses it -> Format encoded or raw data

var mainRoutes = require('./routes/main');
var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
app.use(mainRoutes); // Express is using main routes
app.use(userRoutes);




// Listen on port number 3000 ,
app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("Server is Running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Are you using the `express-flash` node module?  Or some other flash library?

Comment: I am using the express-flash node module.

Comment: Does `req.flash('errors')` contain what you think it should in the GET /signup endpoint?  Can you `req.flash('errors')` before you `res.render('accounts/signup')`?

Comment: Do you make use of the `body-parser` module in your app? Can you post the code for your `app.js`?

Comment: Uploaded server.js aka app.js and yes I use body-parser

Comment: What text is being displayed?

Comment: The mongo db response posted above

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from this line:

```
user.email = req.body.email;
```

This occurs because `req.body.email` is `undefined` which means the email is not unique. You should verify that the request to `/signup` is sent with data from the client.

Comment: I have checked in Postman and the data is being sent, the problem is just occurring with displaying the error. So I think that line of code is fine, as when I submit it does post data to mongodb, the only borken thing is display my own error. Not mongodb error

Answer (score 0):

I just had to check if
 exisitinguser !== null

```
 if (existingUser !== null)
```